# Dictionary with long value

Tags: c#, .net

I have this type of `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict
```

And one of the values is `long` and this is how i try to get it from the `Dictionary`:

```
long wantedid = (long)dict["wantedid"];
```

And this is the Exception i get:

> Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: If that particular value is a `long` then your cast should work. How are you putting the object into the dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you are trying to read is obviously not a `long` value. Since you defined the `Dictionary` as `Dictionary<string, object>`, you may have put objects of any type in it.

Debug the code, and inspect the value of your required element. You can see the data type in the Watch window.

To check the type on runtime, you can try:

```
object o = dict["wantedid"];
if (o is long)
{
    long wantedid = (long)o;
    // ...
}
```

However, if you need to only store `long` values, define the dictionary as `Dictionary<string, long>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the value pair as `object` as it may also contain string value or anything else.

So assume if it contains `"Hello"` then the cast would obviously false.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TryParse to make sure the value is a long.  It could be something like this:

```
    long wantedid;
    bool isLong = long.TryParse(dict["wantedid"].ToString(), out wantedid);
    if (isLong)
    {
        //do whatever you want to because you know the object can be a long       
    }
```